# Samsung Galaxy A54 5G refuses to bypass FRP

Tags: samsung, frp

I have a Samsung Galaxy A54 (A546V) that still has Android 13, on OneUI 5.1, locked with FRP.

I have tried every option that I am aware of, even paid $50 for the Tenorshare one-click removal, and that didn't even work. Using their backup method with the Alliance Shield app still didn't do it. I have been using EFT Pro, SamFW Tool, and ZeroKnox Removal. The one that provides me with the most options and capabilities is the EFT Pro tool, but their newest update does not support the Samsung Galaxy A54. I've even tried to "test-point" method, but that made no difference in how it opened the download mode.

I feel like flashing the firmware with a modded one would do the trick, but modding the firmware myself has been "challenging" (to say the least).

It's a decent phone I really don't want to give up on it. If anybody could provide me with somewhere I can find a modded firmware or something of the sort, that'd be great.

Comment: Sorry, if you have tried everything you can, then I don't think we can provide new ways other than the known attempts from the duplicate.